# Axios not working with <Route path="url/:id">

Tags: reactjs, routes, axios, router

I can't get Axios working when the path of the *Produit* component is **with an id** :

```
<Route exact path="/produit/:id" component={Product} />
```

But **without an :id** Axios is working fine :

```
<Route exact path="/produit" component={Product} />
```

The Produit component with **Axios**:

```
//for the moment I do not use id
const { id } = useParams();
//im doing a Get 
const getAvisData = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await Axios.get(`api/avis?produit=1`).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            setComments(res.data['hydra:member']);
            setCountAvis(res.data['hydra:totalItems']);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getAvisData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when i'm using this path

> path="/produit/:id"

i need to set the the whole url to api :

```
Axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/avis?produit=1`)
```